# Conditional dropdown selection to hide and show item

Tags: sharepoint, dropdown, powerapps, power-platform

I'm new to Power Apps, I'm facing this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D24pR.png)

This is a PA form when I select Projects value in Time entry field the below two fields are enabled Project and Project Role but when I change to other option like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr0Ow.png)

Project and Project role are hidden for other option selected except Projects option in time entry field.

Everything is working fine but problem is coming when I edit any existing records of list and try to change the Time Entry field option when I'm changing the option from Projects to other options the below two fields disabled automatically which is fine but when I save this form after making changes the value of Project and Project Role remains in list which was existed for Projects option before editing.

So what I need here when I edit the existing records so value of Project and Project Role also wipe from SharePoint list when I select options other than project in time entry field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Forms on PowerApps are defined by cards. Cards have two important properties.

- Default, which is the value you pass into the fields and show to the user. Usually this is just the value of the source
- Update, which is the value you write back to the source. Usually, this is just the value of the field

You can do a lot by modifying default and update, which allow you to do all sorts of checks and logic on how different data should be transformed.

In your case, set the update value for project and project role to this

`If(Self.DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Disabled, Blank(), dropdownvaluehere)`

Whenever that card is disabled, it will write nulls to the list, regardless of what the dropdown says. Whenever the card is enabled, it will refer to the dropdownvalue.

As an aside, Consider using a dropdown box instead of a combobox if not necessary, as comboboxes have nice features like letting you select more than one value at a time, but tend to be more temperamental and break and forget values.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the problem is Project and Project role are lookup columns and it's not working by making blank()

Comment: If the project and project role return objects or another column you will have to return that eg {Project: Blank(), ProjectID:Blank()}

Comment: Just to add to that, to write blanks() you may have to turn on Formula Level Error Management in advanced settings for the app, as it fixes a bunch of problems around writing empty values.

Comment: If(cmbTimeEntryType.Selected.Value="Projects",cmbProjectName.Selected,{Id:Coalesce(cmbProjectName.Selected.Id, -1)})

Comment: I used this condition for Update event without enabling experimental feature i.e., formula level error management and its works fine If(cmbTimeEntryType.Selected.Value="Projects",cmbProjectName.Selected,{Id:Coalesce(cmbProjectName.Selected.Id, -1)})